# AngularJS: passing array information along

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table that lists several objects in an array using ng-repeat and I was wondering, if there is an easy way to let the user select one of these objects by clicking on the row and viewing them in a separate `<div>`.

Here's the table:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Type</th>
        <th scope="col">Approver</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns | filter: query" contenteditable="true">
        <td>{{ campaign.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ campaign.type }}</td>
        <td>{{ campaign.approver }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Let's say the user clicked on the first row. He would now see a `<div>` that contains all the information in this row for that object.

```
<div>
 {{campaigns[].name}}
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: what did you try? provide some code
you can do ng-if and show all the info

Comment: Every row has its own $index value. You can use $index to do your work.

Comment: @MohaiminMoin Yes, that's what I was thinking. The user clicks on the row, the index of the object in that row is saved somewhere, and then I just display the array object with that index in a separate <div>. I tried writing a function that saves the index to a variable but it's not working. It's the first controller:

Comment: `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('selCampaign', ['$scope', function(index) {
    $scope.indexCampaign = index;
}]);

myApp.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('js/campaigns.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.campaigns = data;
    });

}]);`

Comment: @mpdegn [edit] the question and add info in it rather than cin omments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be achieved by several way. One of them as below.

```
<table class="table">
<tbody class="table-hover">
<tr>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Type</th>
    <th scope="col">Approver</th>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat-start="campaign in campaigns | filter: query" contenteditable="true" ng-click="campaign.showDetails = !campaign.showDetails">
    <td>{{ campaign.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ campaign.approver }}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="campaign.showDetails">
   Your can dispalay here rest of the information from campaign object.
</tr>
</tbody>
```

You could seed the example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/beNbwp

Comment: This is a nice way to solve the problem. But what if the **ng-show** is used for an object outside the table. Let's say a <div> element?

Comment: Then you need to do this another way. You just use ng-repeat and on ng-click you call a function with the object and show hide the <div> element that exists outside of the table.

Comment: This solution is simple and works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if I understand your problem, the solution could be to use `ng-click` :

(considering campaign.name unique for each campaigns)

```
<tr ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns | filter: query" contenteditable="true" ng-click="doSmth(campaign.name)">
        <td>{{ campaign.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ campaign.type }}</td>
        <td>{{ campaign.approver }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Then in your controller :

```
$scope.doSmth = function(campName) {
    $state.go(campName); //example
};
```

Another solution, using `ui-sref` :

Considering you define a `url: '/folder/campaignPage?name'` in your `$stateProvider`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns | filter: query" contenteditable="true" ui-sref="campaignPage({ name: campaign.name })">
        <td>{{ campaign.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ campaign.type }}</td>
        <td>{{ campaign.approver }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: `ui-sref` is supposed to be used on `<a>` elements to generate it's `href`

Answer (score 0):

Another way  u can do it easily if u also create a button in ng-repeat like

```
 <td><input type="button" value="select" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="populate(campaign )" /></td>
```

And then
`$scope.populate = function (campaign) {
     $scope.Name = campaign.Name;
  }`

It's simple to use.

Comment: I tried that before but I just can't get it to work. Even if I do it the way you did it. This is my cnotroller:
`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('js/campaigns.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.campaigns = data;
    });

    $scope.selCampaign = function (campaign) {
        $scope.Name = campaign.name;
    }
}]);`

`<td><button type="button" class="btn-xs" ng-click="selCampaign(campaign)">Select</button> </td>`